# Complex analysis - inequalities

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove
$|e^z-1|\leq |e^x-1|+e^x|z|$
Where z=x+iy

I tried using $|e^z|=e^x$ and $e^x\geq1+x$ with no success

Comment: Here's a hint: $e^z - 1 = e^z - e^x + e^x - 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: By the triangle inequality,
$$|e^{z} -1 | = |e^{x+iy} - e^{x} + e^{x} - 1| \le |e^{x}-1|+ e^x|e^{iy} -1|.$$
Now sketch the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$ and note that the distance between $e^{iy}$ and $1$ is less than the length of the arc of the circle joining $e^{iy}$ and $1$. The length of this arc is $y$ (modulo $2\pi$) and so....?